# Find $A^{50}$ for a $3\times 3$ matrix

Tags: matrices

> If $$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\1&0&1\\0&1&0\end{bmatrix}$$ then $A^{50}$ is:
>
> 1. $\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\25&1&0\\25&0&1\end{bmatrix}$
> 2. $\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\50&1&0\\50&0&1\end{bmatrix}$
> 3. $\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\48&1&0\\48&0&1\end{bmatrix}$
> 4. $\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\24&1&0\\24&0&1\end{bmatrix}$

For $A$, the eigenvalues are $1, 1, -1$, but I don't know the procedure any further.

Comment: A matrix satisfies its characteristic equation it can help you get a relation between a matrix and its higher powers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sometimes a good way to start a problem like this is just to try a few multiplications and look for a pattern.

$\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \end{array} \right)$ 
$\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \end{array} \right)$$=$
$\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1 \end{array} \right)$ $=A^2$

$\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1 \end{array} \right)$ 
$\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \end{array} \right)$$=$
$\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
2 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 0 \end{array} \right)$ $=A^3$

$\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
2 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 0 \end{array} \right)$ 
$\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \end{array} \right)$$=$
$\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
2 & 1 & 0 \\
2 & 0 & 1 \end{array} \right)$ $=A^4$

Now the pattern should be clear enough to be able to solve the multiple-choice question.  If not, do two more.

Answer (score 3):

**Hints**:

- If $D$ is a diagonal matrix, what is $D\cdot D$? What is $D\cdot D\cdot D$? From that, can you conclude what $D^{50}$ is?
- If $A=PDP^{-1}$, then what is $A\cdot A$? What is $A\cdot A\cdot A$? From that, can you conclude what $A^{50}$ is?

Comment: but this will be lengthier is there any other shortcut method? because this one is MCQ and we have very less time to solve

Comment: @rujulmankad It's a very very simple and quick method once you have enough practice.

Comment: @rujulmankad You could calculate $A^2, A^3$ by hand and hope to spot a pattern and guess your answer from there. If you want to be _certain_, then diagonalization is the fastest way.

Comment: Sorry, but the matrix is not diagonalizable. So we can't proceed with this procedure. Thanks.